# Is there a C# 4 workaround for Path.EndsInDirectorySeperator

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I'm making a software on VS 2010 (Don't ask why, It's just faster to install on my PC and doesn't require having to connect my account) and a tutorial I'm watching mentions this C# 6(?) feature `Path.EndsInDirectorySeperator`

This obviously doesn't work on C#4 so I'm wondering if there's a workaround for it like there is for `nameof`

Comment: Make the effort to use a modern version of VS and .NET

Comment: Oh, thanks I'm cured. Now is there a workaround or will I need to figure it out myself

Comment: If you're working in Windows, just check to see if the last character in your path is a backslash.

Comment: You can always [look at the source code](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/PathInternal.cs) for that method and re-implement it if you need to.

Comment: `nameof` is different; that's an *operator* in C#.  `EndsInDirectorySeparator()` is just a method in the newest versions of the .NET framework.

Comment: So I can't backport it like @Crowcoder said?

Comment: Not `nameof`, no.

Comment: *It's just faster to install on my PC* - and slower to code with because it lacks a huge number of productivity improvements compared to 2022. Of course the faster-to-install-argument totally makes sense if you install it 10 times a day and code with it once a year, but I'd have thought the usage pattern was the other way round...

Answer (score 2):

The comments are correct that you should be using a more modern version of the language and .NET. Visual Studio Community is free, and VS Code is extremely lightweight.

That said, the function is extremely simple. Just write your own.

```
bool EndsInDirectorySeparator(string path)
{
  return path.EndsWith(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar) ||       
         path.EndsWith(Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar)
}
```